# In-place File edit using tie::file

Tags: perl

I have an ncl file which I have to open in a perl script and change some fields and execute the file with a system command. I have to change the file at least four times. On the first run the file is edited, except one field which it does not seem to find. After the first edit the ncl script runs ok. On the second edit it gives the following error:

Couldn't write record: Bad file descriptor at /usr/share/perl/5.26/Tie/File.pm line 908, <$NCLSCRPT> line 151.

Below is a snippet of my code. I give on commented lines, the fields to be edited and below, the search/replace I have used for editing.
The first, second and fourth are edited ok, but the third one never changes.I have given the fields to be edited as data at the end of the code below

I will appreciate assistance on 1) how to edit the third field (s/D+\d{2}.*/D+00 WRF Tmin: $imgsfx[$kk]~C~Issued: 00z ${day}/${month}/${year} Valid: ${day}/${month}/${year}/g) and 2) why after the first edit, I get the above error.
My script is too long to post in its entirety.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
 
use File::Path;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Copy qw(move);
use List::MoreUtils ':all';
use POSIX qw{strftime};
use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);
use Tie::File;

open($NCLSCRPT, " +< /home/zmumba/DA/RnTnTx/Scripts/04_PlotT2mMinMax.ncl") || die "open $NCLSCRPT: failed $! ($^E)";
tie @scrptlines, 'Tie::File', $NCLSCRPT;

for (@scrptlines) {

   #xMinTime = dim_min_n_Wrap(T,0)  - change min to max, max to min
 s/\w+ = dim_.*/$xMin = dim_min_n_Wrap(T,0)/g;

   #wks = gsn_open_wks("x11","Tmin-NODA_02") - change min/max, NODA/DA
 s/wks = gsn_open_wks.*/wks = gsn_open_wks("x11","Tmin-$imgsfx[$kk]_$day")/g;

   #D+00 WRF Tmax: NODA~C~Issued: 09/03/2023 Valid: 04/03/2023 - change min/max, NODA/DA, dates 
 s/D+\d{2}.*/D+00 WRF Tmin: $imgsfx[$kk]~C~Issued: 00z ${day}\/${month}\/${year} Valid: ${day}\/${month}\/${year}/g; #(This does not work)
   

   #plot = gsn_csm_contour_map(wks, xMinTime ,res) - change xMinTime->xMaxTime
 s/plot =.*/plot = gsn_csm_contour_map(wks, $xMin ,res)/g;
}
untie @scrptlines or die $!;
close $NCLSCRPT;

__DATA__
xMinTime = dim_min_n_Wrap(T,0)  - change min to max, max to min
wks = gsn_open_wks("x11","Tmin-NODA_02") - change min/max, NODA/DA
D+00 WRF Tmax: NODA~C~Issued: 09/03/2023 Valid: 04/03/2023 - change min/max, NODA/DA, dates
plot = gsn_csm_contour_map(wks, xMinTime ,res) - change xMinTime->xMaxTime
```

Comment: Tie::File is never the answer. It's insanely slow and use more memory than not using Tie::File, and it doesn't really even simplify anything. Roughly how big is the file?

Comment: hmmm, The `die` throwing the exception has the comment "Should never happen."

Comment: The perl script edits an ncl scripts and then runs to generate graphics. There are four lines to change in the file. The problem is that if I use a simple search and replace the file may go to the end of the file then I have to rewind it seek. Perhaps I made an error of putting g (for global search/replace). I will retry without g and may be avoid tie::file.

Comment: "_There are four lines to change in the file._"  -- And there are "normal" ways to do that.  One: open a file and read it line by line; for each line apply your four regex, and then write the line to a another ("out") file. In the end rename that new file to the old one, if all is well.  It'll be probably much faster, and will use no memory to speak of.  If speed is of _demonstrated_ concern you can tweak the process.

Comment: Then there are libraries that you can use for that as well. An example: [Path::Tiny::edit_lines](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw)  takes care of the file manipulation so the whole thing is one statement, with your regexes.

Comment: Or just read the entire file into memory, modify it, then write it back out. That's why I asked how big the file is.

Comment: @Ikegami the file is very small, 130 lines. It can be read into memory. But nothing is edited. I thought it was going ot end of file, which is why I thogught of tie::file.  Maybe you could help me with the syntax, e.g. in  D+00 WRF Tmax: NODA~C~Issued: 09/03/2023 Valid: 04/03/2023" I want to replace 00, NODA, and the 2 dates so I do s/D+\d{2} WRF.*/D+$fcrange WRF Tmin: $imgsfx[$kk]~C~Issued: 00z ${day}\/${month}\/${year} Valid: ${day}\/${month}\/${year}/g; Butit does not change.

Comment: If you have a problem with a non-Tie::File approach, feel free to post a question about that. This is obviously not appropriate for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

`Tie::File` is an interesting idea to give you random line-oriented access to the entire file, but you are just going through every line sequentially. You might as well use a `while` to go through all the lines in order. One way to handle this is to write to a temp file first so that you end up with a complete file before you modify the original. That way, something doesn't read or use your file while it's in an inconsistent state:

```
use File::Copy qw(copy move);
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
my( $temp_fh, $temp_file ) = tempfile();

my $original = "/home/zmumba/DA/RnTnTx/Scripts/04_PlotT2mMinMax.ncl";

open($NCLSCRPT, '>', $original) 
    || die "open $NCLSCRPT: failed $! ($^E)";

while( <$NCLSCRPT> ) {
    #xMinTime = dim_min_n_Wrap(T,0)  - change min to max, max to min
    s/\w+ = dim_.*/$xMin = dim_min_n_Wrap(T,0)/g;

    ...; # other transformations

    print {$temp_fh} $_;
    }
close $temp;

copy( $original, "$original~"); # keep original in place until replaced!
move( $temp_file, $original );
```

Comment: Thanks @brian. I have to take more time to try this. Currently it is destroying original file which it is supposed to edit.